# How to I create a simple countdown timer for 10 minutes without setInterval()

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple countdown timer for 10 minutes. I have figured out how to do this for the most part but with setInterval() it seems to stop with 2 seconds left every time. I have heard that setInterval() can be very unreliable but I don't know what else to do.

I set the timer to 1 minute and the seconds reset to 3 instead of 59 for time-saving purposes with running the code.

```js
const value = document.querySelector("#time");
const startBtn = document.querySelector("#btn-start")
const resetBtn = document.querySelector("#btn-reset");

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var minute = 1;
    var sec = 3;
    setInterval(function(){
        value.innerHTML = minute + ":" + sec;
        sec--;
        if(sec < 0){
            minute--;
            sec = 3;
        }
        if(sec <=9){
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        if(sec == 0 && minute == 0){
            alert("DONE!");
            location.reload();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        location.reload();
})
```

```css
#main{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#title{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#time{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 50px auto;
}
.function-buttons{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.reset-btn{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
.reset-btn:hover{
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
.start-btn{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.start-btn:hover{
    background: #0096ff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Countdown Timer</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital@0;1&family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 id="title">
                    Countdown Timer
                </h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="countdown-container">
                    <h1 id="title">
                        10 Minute Timer
                    </h1>
                    <span id="time">10:00</span>
                </div>
                <div class="function-buttons">
                    <button class="reset-btn" id="btn-reset">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                    <button class="start-btn" id="btn-start">
                        Start
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a quick glance you are changing ```sec``` to a string.  ```if(sec < 9) { sec = '0' + sec}``` This could throw the comparisons after this off.

Comment: setInterval is the correct method. but indeed it is of no help in measuring time with acceptable precision.
For this you must record the start time and compare it by the intermediate times that you will take at each call cycle by the setInterval, and stop when you reach the target time.

Answer (score -1):

`setInterval` is the best way to do what you want.
It is printing "Done" with 2 second left because you are `sec--` just after updating your DOM.

To solve the problem, you can just do `sec--` and you DOM update at the end of your interval function like so

```js
const value = document.querySelector("#time");
const startBtn = document.querySelector("#btn-start")
const resetBtn = document.querySelector("#btn-reset");

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var minute = 1;
    var sec = 3;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(sec < 0){
            minute--;
            sec = 3;
        }
        if(sec <=9){
            sec = "0" + sec;
        }
        if(sec == 0 && minute == 0){
            alert("DONE!");
            location.reload();
        }
        value.innerHTML = minute + ":" + sec;
        sec--;
    }, 1000);
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        location.reload();
})
```

```css
#main{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#title{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#time{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto 50px auto;
}
.function-buttons{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.reset-btn{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
.reset-btn:hover{
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
.start-btn{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.start-btn:hover{
    background: #0096ff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Countdown Timer</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital@0;1&family=Roboto:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 id="title">
                    Countdown Timer
                </h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="countdown-container">
                    <h1 id="title">
                        10 Minute Timer
                    </h1>
                    <span id="time">10:00</span>
                </div>
                <div class="function-buttons">
                    <button class="reset-btn" id="btn-reset">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                    <button class="start-btn" id="btn-start">
                        Start
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```